# Convert pdf to docx without changing font-size, bold,etc in python3.x

Tags: pdf, python-3.6, doc

I want to convert PDF to docx using python3.x in ubuntu16.x. I gone through the code given below:

```
for top, dirs, files in os.walk(pdfdir):
  for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        i = i + 1
        abspath_pdf = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(top, filename))

        print 'Converting {0} into .doc format..'.format(abspath_pdf)
        subprocess.call('{0} --invisible --convert-to doc{1} --outdir "{2}" "{3}"'
                        .format(lowriter, outfilter, docdir, abspath_pdf), shell=True)
```

But its not working for me. Can anyone help for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aspose.Words Cloud to convert PDF to MS Word formats
https://products.aspose.cloud/words/python
You should also note that PDF format is fixed page format, and MS Words formats are flow formats. This makes conversion from PDF to MS Word quite difficult task. Aspose.Words Cloud does recognition of elements in PDF so the output is editable in MS Word. See the following link to learn more about PDF to Word conversion https://docs.aspose.cloud/display/wordscloud/Convert+PDF+Document+to+Word